# How to use StyleCop from command line?

Tags: c#, stylecop

Is there a way to use StyleCop 4.5 from the command line on an individual source file, like `stylecop HelloWorld.cs`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't. It's not a feature of stylecop, it only integrates with VS2008/2010 and MsBuild

There is [this project](http://sourceforge.net/projects/stylecopcmd/) at sourceforge that *may* do what you're looking for.  DISCLAIMER: I have not tried it.

Answer (score 6):

To revive an old thread...

https://github.com/Nylle/StyleCop.Console seems to fit the job nicely.

Answer (score 3):

[Here is](http://stylecopplus.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Running%20StyleCop%20from%20Your%20Code) also an article descibing how to create a simple C# console app running StyleCop over specified file.

Feel free to create your own runner which will be able to process results in any way you want.

Answer (score 2):

There is [this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/stylecopcli) project available on [SourceForge.net](http://sourceforge.net) that you can use from the command-line.

Answer (score 1):

There's also [StyleCopCmd](http://akutz.wordpress.com/2008/10/29/introducing-stylecopcmd/), a command-line wrapper and NAnt task for StyleCop.