# Error 1 occurs when inspecting with StyleCopCLI, a C# inspection tool

Tags: c#

I would like to inspect a single cs file retrieved from Github using StyleCopCLI.
I am running the following command in PowerShell.
StyleCopCLI.exe -cs ImageProcessor.cs

The output is as follows, and the output file contains the following
output =>
`1 violations encountered.`

output file =>

```
<StyleCopViolations>
  <Violation LineNumber="1" RuleNamespace="StyleCop.CoreParser" Rule="ExceptionOccurred" RuleId="SA0001">An exception occurred while parsing ArgumentException, The string must not be empty or null
Parameter name:location.</Violation>.
</StyleCopViolations>
```

I would like to download the cs files with bug reports from Github and run StyleCopCLI inspections on each file.
I would like to investigate how well the buggy file complies with the convention.
I would like to know if StyleCop needs to be installed separately, and if so, what version.

If there are any kind souls out there who can give a hand to a newbie, please answer.
Translated by Deeple.

I would like to download the cs files with bug reports from Github and run StyleCopCLI inspections on each file.
I would like to investigate how well the buggy file complies with the convention.
I looked into it, but could not even figure out which document to read.
If there are any kind souls out there who can give a hand to a newbie, please answer. Translated by Deeple.

Comment: did you read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6931946/how-to-use-stylecop-from-command-line

Comment: and this https://bigfont.ca/install-and-use-stylecop-in-a-net-or-net-core-project-from-the-command-line/

Comment: Of course I looked at that article, but I don't think it's covered in my case.
I only collect changed files of commits related to bugs through GithubAPI.
I have come to the conclusion that it cannot be used in this case because it is not a file for the entire project.
Any other clues you can give me would be appreciated.